# Proving that a discrete set percentage approximates always the value of percentage

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have discrete set $A$ and a percentage number $ 0 \leq P \leq 1$. The values within $A$ are not important, they could be $(1,1,1,1,1)$. $l(A)$ is the length(size) of $A$.

Is there any way that I can prove that:

$\frac{\lfloor l(A)*P \rceil}{l(A)} = P$

For larger versions of $A$ this probably holds true, but how can I express that even for smaller size $A$ the result will approximate $P$? Does it even hold? Or is there a way that I can demonstrate at what point the above equation starts approximating $P$ instead of producing the exact $P$. In other words, can I get the minimum $l(A)$ to always produce an exact $P$ using the above equation?

Examples:

$\frac{\lfloor l(A)*P \rceil}{l(A)} = \frac{\lfloor 10*0.7 \rceil}{10} = 0.7$

But the following example fails

$\frac{\lfloor l(A)*P \rceil}{l(A)} = \frac{\lfloor 3*0.7 \rceil}{3} = 0.666 \ne 0.7$

Comment: Can you give a numerical example?

Comment: what type of rounding are you using - regular, up- or down-?

Comment: $ell(A)$ is just a number, so your equation is true without the floor and ceiling.  I don't understand the use of the floor and ceiling.  Are you trying to say the equation is true with the value somewhere between the floor and ceiling?

Comment: Also, what's the point of having a set $A$? Why not just use a variable, $n$ say, instead of $\ell(A)$?

Comment: It is for an algorithm, I am trying to prove that given a percentage of a text, composed of a set of characters, no matter what percentage value is selected the approximation after rounding will always be close to the original selected percentage. The round used is lower higher on the .5 middle.

Comment: Perhaps another way of looking at the problem is asking how much deviation is added or subtracted from P due to rounding. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r(x)$ be the closest integer to $x$ (with upwards rounding in the middle).$\,$ Then

$$x - \frac{1}{2} < r(x) \le x + \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus, if $n>0,$

\begin{align*}
&nP - \frac{1}{2} \;<\; r(nP) \;\le\; nP + \frac{1}{2}\\[12pt]
\implies\;&\frac{nP - \frac{1}{2}}{n} \;<\; \frac{r(nP)}{n} \;\le\; \frac{nP + \frac{1}{2}}{n}\\[12pt]
\implies\;&P - \frac{1}{2n} \;<\;\frac{r(nP)}{n} \;\le\; P + \frac{1}{2n}]
\end{align*}

Comment: WOW! You have a great mind! The lower and higher bounds do help to understand the point through which the effect is the worse. So as n grows the effect is negligible.